# Ошибка конверсии void* в char* при использовании функции malloc

Tags: c++

Почему-то ловлю ошибку конверсии void* в char* при использовании функции malloc.

```
char *strLine = (char *)malloc(256);
strLine = memset(strLine, 0x00, 256);
```

Ошибка возникает именно во второй строчке. Компилятор указывает мне, мол, уважаемый пользователь, вы неверно объявили переменную strLine. Погуглил - нашёл очень похожую проблему тоже с использованием **malloc**, но там всё решилось добавлением этого самого **(char *)**перед malloc. Так в чём же дело? Почему мне это не помогает?

Comment: Код, по сути, сишный. Но из-за компиляции в режиме C++ `void*` неявно в `char*` не преобразуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, проблема у вас во второй строчке, а не в первой: `strLine` имеет тип `char*`, а `memset` возвращает `void*`.

Вы могли бы скастить возвращаемое `memset`'ом значение в `char*`. Но оно вам в принципе вовсе не нужно. Просто напишите

```
memset(strLine, 0x00, 256);
```

Вы ж всё равно уже аллоцировали память, ничего нового из `memset` к вам не придёт.

Comment: @Nikolas: Зря вы удалили ответ, он правильный же.